# Proof Verification: Prove by induction that if $n_1, n_2,\cdots,n_t$ are even integers, then $n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_t$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

Proof: Proceed by induction

Base case $P(t=1)=n_1$, which is even since $n$ is an even integer. True.
Assume $P(t)$, i.e. if $n_1,n_2,\cdots n_t$ are even, then $n_1+n_2+...+n_t$ is even, is true.

Inductive step: $P(t+1)=n_1+n_2+...n_t+n_{t+1}$. Since $n_1+n_2+...+n_t$ is assumed to be even and $n_{t+1}$ is even, an even $+$ even gives an even number. Therefore $P(t+1)$ is shown to be true by induction.

Please let me know if this proof is satisfactory as I am relatively new to induction proofs.

Comment: Satisfactory, but your MathJax isn't.

Comment: For reference: [Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Don't you need to prove that the sum of $t$ terms that are even is itself even rather than just asserting it to be true?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern: No, that's the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but some of your notation and phrasing is off.

First, note that a statement like "$P(t=1)=n_1$" doesn't make sense, for several reasons.  First, you've never defined what $P(t)$ means.  Second, even if you had defined it, $P(t=1)$ would not make sense; instead you would just write $P(1)$.  Third, the usual thing to call "$P(t)$" here would be the *statement* that if $n_1,\dots,n_t$ are even integers, then so is their sum.  So $P(t)$ (or $P(1)$) is an entire statement, not just a number.  It doesn't make sense to say $P(1)=n_1$.

What you can instead say for your base case (after defining what $P(t)$ means) is something like:

> To prove $P(1)$, suppose $n_1$ is an even integer. Then the sum we must prove is even is just $n_1$, which we know to be even.

Note how I clearly introduced the variable $n_1$ with "suppose $n_1$ is an even integer" before proceeding to prove anything.  This is in general a good practice when proving a "for all" statement: you first start by explicitly mentioning that you are considering a particular instance of the statement.

There are similar issues with your phrasing in the inductive step.  Also, the induction hypothesis (where you assume that $P(t)$ is true) should be  the start of the inductive step, rather than the end of the base case.

Comment: Does this look better: Assume P(t), i.e. if n1, n2,...,nt are even, then n1+n2+...+nt is even, is true. Then Since n1+n2+...+nt is assumed to be even and nt+1 is even, an even + even gives an even number. Therefore P(t+1) is shown to be true by induction.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot better!  My main suggestion would be that you explicitly introduce the variables $n_1,\dots,n_{t+1}$ after your first sentence, like I did for the base case.